# How to track e-mail read status using IMAP

Tags: email, exchange-server, imap, exchange-server-2016

I have to research the user reactions to an incoming phishing mail.
Therefore i'm trying to track if a user opened an e-mail. I'm using an Exchange Server and have complete access to the logfiles. I want to use the imap flags (/Seen, /Answered etc.) to get this information.
My problem is, that i can't connect my imap log to a message-id or something different unique identifier.

Here an example of the imap log

2019-07-26T19:01:47.641Z,000000000000001B,15,[fe80::1435:3fe7:d31e:230f%14]:1993,[fe80::1435:3fe7:d31e:230f%14]:22505,alicetracker,1,24,57,uid+fetch,fetch 2:* (FLAGS),"R=OK;Rows=1;UidValidity=14;UidNext=2;ActivityContextData=Dbl:BudgUse.T[]=0.945299983024597;Budget=""Owner:Sid~S-1-5-21-2443813523-3910580689-2609561915-1147~Imap~false,Conn:1,MaxConn:Unlimited,MaxBurst:3600000,Balance:3600000,Cutoff:Unlimited,RechargeRate:600000,Policy:GlobalThrottlingPolicy_6ead7ca9-720e-4f9c-8a7c-eaaf9fd5866e,IsServiceAccount:False,LiveTime:00:07:08.8466978""",

Is there any way to manipulate the Exchange-Server that i can use the imap-logs for that issue?

Thanks!

Comment: That log line says `…,uid+fetch,fetch 2:* (FLAGS),…` which is enough to identify the command and the message used. If you read [RFC 3501](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501), particularly [the sections on FETCH](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.5) and [STORE](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.6), you'll be able to derive the seen/answered state for each message at each moment in time.

Comment: But where is the connection to a e-mail send by me? I can see, that the e-mail 2 in the mailbox is seen, but not exactly which e-mail because the Message-ID is not shown in the Log. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: 2 is a long-term stable identifier within a mailbox (a folder). It's called a UID. 2:* means "all messages from 2 to the last, inclusive". If you want the message-id, you can retrieve it based on that 2.

Comment: Really? Thanks, that helps me a lot! Do you have a advice, which command i have to use for receiving the Message-ID?

Comment: `uid fetch 2 body.peek[header.fields (message-id)]`. I think you will find this task easier to achieve if you sit down and read the specification, particularly [the section about fetch/uid fetch](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.5).

Comment: But i'm not on the client side, i controll the server side and if i am not wrong, i can not execute fetch commands for a special mailbox/user.
Neverless i'll try to find the solution in the specification :) 
Thanks!